# Logical OR with Strings

Tags: java, logical-operators

I have an `if` statement where one of two conditions can be met, but I don't want to use nested `if`.

For example, what I would like is to have;

```
String s;

if(s == "foo" || "bar") {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

However, operator `||` cannot be applied to a `String`.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: if (s.equals("foo") || s.equals("bar")) { ... }

Comment: And nullsafe: `if("foo".equals(s) || "bar".equals(s)) {. . .}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex:

```
String s = "foo";
if (s.matches("foo|bar"))
    // true
else
    // false
```

Comment: It should be noted that `String.matches()` internally calls `Pattern.matches()`, which again calls `Pattern.compile()`, making it quite a heavy operation (compared to a simple `equals()` comparison). Just something to keep in mind if the code in question is called really frequently.

Answer (score 2):

`equals()` method should be used to compare `Strings`.

if statements evaluate as booleans (`true` or `false`).
Also, reverse the order of your `equals` comparison to avoid NPE's.

```
String s;

if ("foo".equals(s) || "bar".equals(s)) {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals` to compare strings in Java:

```
String s;

if(s.equals("foo") || s.equals("bar")) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative to those already given:

```
if (Arrays.asList("foo", "bar").contains(s)) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

Of course, you can build the collection beforehand:

```
Set<String> wordsToMatch = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
```

and then use it over and over:

```
if (wordsToMatch.contains(s)) {
  // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the `Strings` incorrectly.

below shows how to compare `Strings` using `equals()` method of the `String` class.

```
String s;

if(s.equals("foo") || s.equals("bar")) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

[Further reading regarding how to compare Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

```
if(s.equals("foo") || s.equals("bar")){
   //Your Code
}
```

Comment: Remember to use `.equals` and not `==`!